# spring-data-neo4j, fetching relatedTo entity manully

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

```
@NodeEntity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Employee {
    @GraphId
    private Long graphId;

    @Indexed
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String password;

    @RelatedTo(type = "REPORT_TO", direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    private Department department;
}
```

I know spring-data-neo4j can use @Fetch to get Department data when get Employee entity, but not every time I need Department when get Employee, so how can I fetching department manully? The @Fetch annotation is not flexible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Neo4jTemplate#fetch (T)` to do manually what `@Fetch` does automagically.

See [api doc here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/3.1.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/support/Neo4jTemplate.html#fetch%28T%29).

Comment: hi, jiaderberg, I'm not sure how to use it. As if my code is 'Employee find = employeeRepository.findByNameAndPassword(employee.getName(), employee.getPassword());', so how can I use template to fetch department? Thanks

Comment: Pass the entity you want to fetch to the fetch method. `Department d = template.fetch (employee.getDepartment ());` or something similar. Or if the employee is detached, `Employee e = template.fetch (repository.findByXXX (xxx));`

Comment: @jiaderberg, Thanks for your answer, I have another question, could you help me ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24859704/spring-neo4j-save-entity-and-add-relationship-to-an-existing-node